# How to find an object with specific field values in a std::set?

Tags: c++, stl, find, set

I call a method which returns `std::set<T> const&` where `T` is a class type. What I'm trying to achieve is to check whether the set contains an object of type `T` with specific field values for an assertion in a automated test. This check should be done for multiple objects.

Here is a simple example:
Let the type `T` be `Car` so an example `set` contains a bunch of cars. Now I want to find a car with a specific color **and** a specific number of doors **and** a specific top speed in that set. If **that** car is found the first assertion is true and the next car with other field values should be found.

I'm not allowed to change the implementation of `T`. The usage of Boost would be OK.

How would you do that?

Comment: Do you want to compose the rule (red + sedan + 200kph) at run time? Or is hard-coding good enough?

Comment: Hardcoded rules would be enough.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This depends on the implementation of `T`. Let's stick with your example of a class `Car`. Suppose that class looks something like this:

```
class Car {
public:
    Car(std::string color, unsigned int number_of_doors,
        unsigned int top_speed);
    // getters for all these attributes
    // implementation of operator< as required for std::set
};
```

The `operator<` should order instances of `Car` based on **all attributes** in order to make searching for all attributes possible. Otherwise you will get incorrect results.

So basically, you can construct an instance of car using just these attributes. In that case, you can use `std::set::find` and supply a temporary instance of `Car` with the attributes you are looking for:

```
car_set.find(Car("green", 4, 120));
```

If you want to search for an instance of `Car` specifying only a subset of its attributes, like all green cars, you can use `std::find_if` with a custom predicate:

```
struct find_by_color {
    find_by_color(const std::string & color) : color(color) {}
    bool operator()(const Car & car) {
        return car.color == color;
    }
private:
    std::string color;
};

// in your code

std::set<Car>::iterator result = std::find_if(cars.begin(), cars.end(), 
                                              find_by_color("green"));
if(result != cars.end()) {
    // we found something
}
else {
    // no match
}
```

Note that the second solution has linear complexity, because it cannot rely on any ordering that may or may not exists for the predicate you use. The first solution however has logarithmic complexity, as it can benefit from the order of an `std::set`.

If, as suggested by @Betas comment on your question, you want to compose the predicates at runtime, you would have to write some helper-classes to compose different predicates.

Comment: Lexicographical order ftw. Good catch. If you want more general queries however this has limitations (find *all* the volvo red cars)

Comment: Use #include <algorithm> to get the std::find_if routine.

Answer (score 1):

When faced to such problems, I usually maintain:

- A `std::deque` or `std::vector` of cars
- For each property you want to look up against, a `std::multiset` of pointers to cars, sorted by the property value.

I carefully hide those containers inside a class which allows me to insert cars.

The querying interface may vary, but usually, you make advantage of `multiset::equal_range`, `std::sort` and `std::set_intersection`.

If you want a red Volvo whatever... car, you

1. extract by `equal_range` all the red cars, giving you an iterator pair
2. extract by `equal_range` all the Volvo cars, giving you an iterator pair
3. ...
4. Sort all these ranges by a common predicate, say by pointer address
5. Apply repeatedly `set_intersection` into a `std::deque`.

Another way is to store the cars into a `deque`, enumerate them and pick the one which satisfies all your properties, using `std::find`. This may have worse complexity however (it depends on how many red cars you have for isntance)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want `std::find_if`, with a predicate function object that checks the properties you're interested in. It might look something like this:

```
struct FindCar {
    FindCar(Colour colour, int doors, double top_speed) :
        colour(colour), doors(doors), top_speed(top_speed) {}

    bool operator()(Car const & car) const {
        return car.colour == colour
            && car.doors == doors
            && car.top_speed == top_speed;
    }

    Colour colour;
    int doors;
    double top_speed;
};

std::set<Car> const & cars = get_a_set_of_cars();
std::set<Car>::const_iterator my_car =
    std::find_if(cars.begin(), cars.end(), FindCar(Red, 5, 113));
```

In C++0x, you could replace the "FindCar" class with a lambda to make the code a bit shorter.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of `std::set`, right? `std::set` is able to find things in `O(log(n))` using binary search. If you're doing this, try to figure out how to use `std::set::find` or `std::binary_search`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try overriding operator<(const T& a, const T& b) to impose an order on those attributes, so std::set:find(const T& x) will return the first no less than x.

Ej:

```
bool operator<(const Car& a, const Car& b)
{
    return a.color<b.color || (a.color==b.color && a.doors<b.doors) || (a.color==b.color && a.doors==b.doors && a.top_speed<b.top_speed);
}

std::set<Car> cars;
Car x;
cars.find(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The std::set allows you to provide your own comparison function, as in

```
template < class Key, class Compare = less<Key>,
       class Allocator = allocator<Key> > class set;
```

Only compare the values you care about and it will act as if objects with those values are =. Note that you will probably need a multiset for this.

This would be the way to do it if you really care about logn performance.